# My Minecraft 1.16.3 keeps crashing from boot-up. As soon as the red background, white bar and white "Mojang" symbol appears, it crashes. Any Fixes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Just as title says, minecraft keeps breaking. I even tried deleting minecraft and re-installing it, but again to no avail.

CRASH REPORT:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Who set us up the TNT?

Time: 14/10/20 9:24 PM
Description: Exception in server tick loop

java.lang.StackOverflowError: Exception in server tick loop
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.toArray(Iterables.java:295)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.copyOf(ImmutableMap.java:406)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.copyOf(ImmutableMap.java:391)
    at cru.(SourceFile:54)
    at cru.(SourceFile:28)
    at cru$a.a(SourceFile:217)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:639)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:279)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:662)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:688)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:281)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:283)
    at bkb.b(SourceFile:15)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bpe.a(SourceFile:195)
    at byg.a(SourceFile:247)
    at bjt.a(SourceFile:233)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.15
    Minecraft Version ID: 1.15
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_51, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 775769120 bytes (739 MB) / 1845493760 bytes (1760 MB) up to 2147483648 bytes (2048 MB)
    CPUs: 8
    JVM Flags: 9 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xss1M -Xmx2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
    Player Count: 1 / 8; [xe['ZacianX'/6238, l='New World', x=7.79, y=1.49, z=58.71]]
    Data Packs: vanilla
    Type: Integrated Server (map_client.txt)
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and both client + server brands are untouched.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't connect to my Minecraft server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/343980/i-cant-connect-to-my-minecraft-server)

Comment: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` and `java.lang.StackOverflowError: Exception in server tick loop` are two different exceptions, so is probably not a dupe.

Comment: This error code should probably be added to the community wiki answer in [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/96496/4797)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think [I can't connect to my Minecraft server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/343980/i-cant-connect-to-my-minecraft-server) would answer your problem. The problem there is an out-of-memory exception. Here we have a stack overflow exception.

This happens when a program tries to create too many levels of recursion. With each level of recursion it has to copy and reserve a bit of memory (usually a megabyte or so) known as the *stack* where local variables are kept. Programming languages usually set reasonable limits on the size of the stack, that are large enough that most programs won't naturally have to deal with this.

The function `bkb.b(SourceFile:15)` seems to call itself recursively via 5 other functions. It's likely there's some kind of infinite loop going on. I recommend doing the same as the other question: File a bug report.

In order for us to help you we would need to decompile, reverse-engineer and deobfuscate the program. On the other hand, if you provided that data to [Mojang](https://bugs.mojang.com/), they'd be able to find it in the original (readable!) source code.